# jQuery animation bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a really annoying bug with my menu tab, jQuery hover effect.

Here is the link ( http://pavilioncreative.com )

If you refresh your page and quickly place your mouse curser over the menu tab and then move out the jQuery animation will work back to front.

If you click on the menu tab and then click of the menu tab the same thing will happen again as the jQuery animation will work back to front!

Can any one help with this ? its really frustrating!!

Thanks

Comment: Something to do with `+=5px`, it needs to be absolute, not relative. And also, why do you have `$(document).ready(function(){})` so much?

Comment: SO discourages questions that can't be solved without linking out to external content. In this case, you'll get an answer, fix the problem, then this question will not make any sense (and just becomes old rotten content).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for either [`finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/) or [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: @Mirabilis Please don't apologise for me, and please don't ask the user to host code critical to solving the problem on a 3rd party site. I'm not being intimidating. I'm just telling the user how to ask questions that won't get closed down. There's no "soft" way to do this.

Comment: @spender, your comment looks better now. It did look a little intimidating at first, especially for a new user.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, like many suggested, please add a jsfiddle like this https://jsfiddle.net/8qsq2pcL/2/
Please read the guidelines. The goal is to prevent you editing external sites which voided the purpose of the question.

2) Your problem with javascript is with the counter. The counter prevents the trigger of hoverout when hoverin is not activated.

```
var hoverIn = false; //You need this counter to detect whether animate occurs.
$(".menu_tab").hover(function() {
    if (hoverIn)return; //if the hover is activated, it stops the function

  //I also took the liberty to help you add stop to prevent multiple hover. Feel free to implement that else where
  $(".barOne").stop(true, true).animate({
    "bottom": "+=5px"
  }, "fast");
  $(".barThree").stop(true, true).animate({
    "top": "+=5px"
  }, "fast");
  hoverIn = true;
}, function() {
    if (!hoverIn)return; //if the hover is deactivated, it stops this function
  $(".barOne").stop(true, true).animate({
    "bottom": "-=5px"
  }, 300);
  $(".barThree").stop(true, true).animate({
    "top": "-=5px"
  }, 300);
  hoverIn = false;
});
```

3) Your javascript should look cleaner with less code. I cannot fix every issue you have, but all the comments are correct especially too many `$(document).ready(function(){})`. You just need one big one. That is it.

Answer (score 1):

The bug occurs, because the mouse is placed over the .menu_tab before the document is ready, and the animations you apply to the ".menu_tab".hover do not fire until the document is ready. Moe's answer should do the trick. But you should put menuOn back to false when the second part of the animation is through.

But, yes, you should really have made a fiddle or something, to make this question useful to others than you. :-)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer I can't see Moe's answer ? sorry I'm new to this site and I'm getting used to the navigation.

Comment: Oh, I can't either any more. But Stanley1943 did the same thing.